# Why only first controller is working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 Controllers in Laravel as

```
Route::get('/books/{slug}', 'BooksController@slugShow');
Route::get('/books/{alphabet}', 'BooksController@showByAlphabet');
```

Both controllers are working fine when using only one but when I put them both in Routs file only the first one works.

slug urls are like

```
https://www.example.com/books/once_upon_a_time
```

and Alphabets urls are list of books starting with an alphabet

```
https://www.example.com/books/a
```

How Can I make them both work and I also want urls of alphabets to not work if there are more than a single character in the url like

```
https://www.example.com/books/aa
or
https://www.example.com/books/once
```

Comment: Post your controller code as well so that we can figure out what is the error and also post what error you are getting.

Comment: you can try to make different routes for each request like `/books/slug/{slug}` and `/books/alphabet/{alphabet}`

Comment: Don't use the same route for different functionality. A slug is a slug, doesn' matter if its a word or a sentene

Comment: I cannot change it to `/books/alphabet/{alphabet}` but I can change slug to `/books/{id}/{slug}` but that creates a problem for me. How can I create a check that both id and slug must stay same and one cannot manipulate the slug.

Answer (score 4):

Use like this

```
Route::get('/books/{alphabet}', 'BooksController@showByAlphabet')->where(['alphabet' => '[a-z]{1,1}']);
Route::get('/books/{slug}', 'BooksController@slugShow');
```

When the `{alphabet}` route is not valid, it will fallback to slug.

Comment: this is the right solution, missing one detail. put the `{alphabet}` route before the `{slug}` route for it to work.

Comment: happy to help and accept as well so other can get help

Answer (score 3):

You should change Route and try it.

```
Route::get('/books/alphabet/{alphabet}', 'BooksController@showByAlphabet');
```

Because you had pass the same URl and application is not allow to same route name.

Comment: @Nitin Gandhi If my answer is solved your concern then please accept my answer.

Comment: this solution forces a change in the route structure. Shaielndra's solution keeps the same structure and answers the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

patterns are identical ... that's the problem.
You can add a where condition to your route to limit to 1 char for alphabet

`Route::get('/books/{alphabet}', 'BooksController@showByAlphabet')->where(['alphabet' => '[a-z]']);`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the routes as

```
Route::get('/books/{slug}', 'BooksController@slugShow');
Route::get('/books/{alphabet}', 'BooksController@showByAlphabet');
```

In both the routes `/books/{id}` is read by laravel thus `{slug}` and `{alphabet}` are taken as id.For using different method the url can be changed as `/books/slug/{slug}` and for alphabets `/books/alphabets/{alphabet}`.

In this way you can use both URLs properly and method will be called.